# Get repeated events with the Solspace Calendar and Element API plugins

Tags: plugin-elementapi, plugin-solspacecalendar

When looping through all events in Twig, repeated events will continuously come in. On a weekly event, for instance, it pulls one for this week, one for next week, etc. Lets say I have a meeting event set to repeat weekly, it would come back like this:

```
{% for event in craft.calendar.events %} ...

Meeting Event
Meeting Event
Meeting Event
...
```

I'm looking to load events asynchronously with the Element API plugin but I'm only able to get back each event once (even the repeated ones). How do I achieve the same behavior? Here is the basic setup:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'api/events.json' => function() {
      return [
        'elementType' => 'Calendar_Event'
      ];
    }
  ]
];
```

And it only returns:

```
Meeting Event
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this won't be possible with Solspace Calendar since we are extending `ElementCriteria` with `Calendar_EventCriteriaModel`, which has a layer on top of it allowing us to build recurring events and return a padded list of events. We also return `Event` objects instead of `EventModel` objects, because working with Craft Dates makes it difficult/impossible for Calendar to have the dates it needs. Sorry :/

Comment: FWIW, in Craft 3 we've stop extending PHP's Date class with one of our own.

Answer (score 1):

While not the ideal solution, there seems to be enough meta information to build out the recurring events manually.

```
'transformer' => function(Calendar_EventModel $event) {
  $exceptions = [];
  foreach($event->exceptions as $exception) {
    $exceptions[] = $exception->date;
  }

  return [
    'id' => $event->id,
    'title' => $event->title,
    'calendarId' => $event->calendarId,
    'slug' => $event->slug,
    'startDate' => $event->startDate,
    'endDate' => $event->endDate,
    'freq' => $event->$freq,
    'interval' => $event->interval,
    'exceptions' => $exceptions,
    'byMonth' => $event->byMonth,
    'byYearDay' => $event->byYearDay,
    'byMonthDay' => $event->byMonthDay,
    'byDay' => $event->byDay
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got the [Element API syntax](https://github.com/theolampert/ElementAPI#setup) wrong.  Try this:

```
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/events.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Calendar_Event',
            'transformer' => function(Calendar_EventModel $event) {
                return [
                    'title' => $event->title,
                ];
            },
        ],
    ]
];
```

Note that I don't have the Calendar plugin, so I can't test this, and I'm guessing that their event model class is called `Calendar_EventModel`, so you'll want to verify that.  You can return any of the properties they have listed here: https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/event/

Comment: The code I have gives the same result as yours (with different fields of course as I didn't specify a transformer..), if there's an error I don't see it.  The issue isn't with the fields, it's the number of records returned.

Comment: I found the event model class looking in the craft_elements table, didn't see it in the documentation but it's the only option I see related to the Calendar plugin so I assume it is correct

Comment: fyi I'm using the function syntax because I have a parameter, I removed some code for the sake of a simple example :)

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Forgot you could specify a closure for an endpoint. Will see if I can get a copy of the plugin from Solspace.

Comment: Oh cool thanks. There's a param loadOccurrences to the template function here, but I'm not sure how it relates to the element api. It doesn't seem to respect it. https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/calendar.events